# Getting a exitcode 2 error using celery in flask

Tags: python, celery

Question on flask and celery -

```
init.py

from celery import Celery
from flask import Flask
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'redis://localhost'
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://localhost'

celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)
```

```
training.py

from project import celery

training = Blueprint('training', __name__)

@training.route('/projectdetails/training', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def start_training():

    train_test.delay()

    return render_template('test.html')

@celery.task()
def train_test():
  # a ML training task.
```

I have my redis server on and my celery worker `celery -A myproject.celery worker --loglevel=info` .

This is an error I keep getting -

```
[2021-04-01 17:25:11,604: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-8' pid:67580 exited with 'exitcode 2'
[2021-04-01 17:25:11,619: ERROR/MainProcess] Task handler raised error: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: exitcode 2.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rohankamath/Desktop/lol/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1267, in mark_as_worker_lost
    human_status(exitcode)),
billiard.exceptions.WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: exitcode 2.
```

Tried searching the meaning on exitcode2, couldn't find anything.

Comment: Same here. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me when there was some import error in my code. Could you try running without celery(directly calling the main function) and see if it is working?